# camel-salesforce-maven-plugin - camel-saleforce prefix not found

Tags: apache-camel, maven-plugin

I am trying to generate saleforce DTO using following command :

```
mvn camel-salesforce:generate -DcamelSalesforce.clientId=<clientid> -DcamelSalesforce.clientSecret=<clientsecret> -DcamelSalesforce.userName=<username> -DcamelSalesforce.password=<password>
```

When I run it, I get error

> camel-salesforce prefix not found ...

However if I run it like

`mvn org.apache.camel.maven:camel-salesforce-maven-plugin:generate` ..., it works.

Has anyone else had this issue?

Comment: Its a maven thing, when you do not have the fully name of the plugin, you need to declare it in your local pom.xml file.

Comment: I checked camel-salesforce-maven-plugin pom, and generate prefix is defined. Here is what solved my issue, in case someone else run into this issue. I added following in my maven settings.xml. It is explained in https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-plugin-prefix-mapping.html in "Configuring Maven to Search for Plugins" section: <pluginGroups>
  <pluginGroup>org.apache.camel.maven</pluginGroup>
 </pluginGroups>